# HowTo: Display progress dialog using IFileOperation

Tags: c++, interface, com, mfc, windows-shell

I’m trying to get a progress dialog to display for my copy operation in some sample code.  I’m using [IFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771(v=vs.85).aspx) because I found that using *SHFileOperation* will **not** display a progress dialog if the files have already been copied to the target location.  My hope is that IFileOperation is a little more sophisticated and can handle that situation.
Here’s the sample code I’ve tried….

```
CComPtr<IOperationsProgressDialog> opProgressDlg;
HRESULT hr = opProgressDlg.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ProgressDialog);

CComPtr<IFileOperation> fileOp;
hr = fileOp.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation);
hr = fileOp->SetOperationFlags(FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION | FOFX_PRESERVEFILEEXTENSIONS | FOFX_NOMINIMIZEBOX);
hr = fileOp->SetProgressDialog(opProgressDlg);

hr = opProgressDlg->StartProgressDialog(m_hWnd, OPPROGDLG_DEFAULT);
hr = opProgressDlg->SetMode(PDM_DEFAULT);
hr = opProgressDlg->SetOperation(SPACTION_COPYING);
oldDirectory += _T("*.*");

CFileFind finder;
BOOL bWorking = finder.FindFile(oldDirectory);
while (bWorking)
    {
    bWorking = finder.FindNextFile();
    if (finder.IsDots())
        continue;
    CString name = finder.GetFilePath();
    IShellItem *psiFrom = nullptr;
    hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(CT2CW(name), NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psiFrom));
    IShellItem *psiTo = NULL;
    hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(CT2CW(newDirectory), NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psiTo));
    hr = fileOp->CopyItem(psiFrom, psiTo, CT2CW(finder.GetFileName()), NULL);
    //hr = opProgressDlg->UpdateLocations(psiFrom, psiTo, psiTo);
    }

opProgressDlg->StopProgressDialog();

hr = fileOp->PerformOperations();
```

The sample is trying to copy **all** files and folders from one location (oldDirectory) to another (newDirectory).  **The copy operation does copy everything correctly**.  I’m looking for help in getting the progress dialog to display during the operation.  According to IFileOperation, I should be able to set the progress dialog through [IOperationsProgressDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775368(v=vs.85).aspx).  The documentation for this is extremely thin.  I have not been able to find any samples showing how to fit the two together.  Does anyone have experience with these two interfaces?

Comment: Don't you get a progress dialog automatically? Anyway I've not played with it myself but the docs for `IOperationsProgressDialog::StartProgressDialog` say that it should be created on a separate thread.

Comment: @JonathanPotter You would think that's the case, but, it isn't from what I've found.  The fact that you need to establish an additional interface for the progress dialog has me a bit confused.  I can certainly try it in another thread, but, I feel like there's more to it than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need progress dialog, then remove the reference to `IOperationsProgressDialog`

`CopyItem` only prepares the items for copying, therefore `IOperationsProgressDialog::Update...` will not update any UI. Actual copying begins when `PerformOperations` is called.

UI dialog won't show if there are only a few files, because it's done too quickly. Maybe you want to remove `FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION` to make it easier for testing. This should be exact same thing as `SHFileOperation`.

```
CString srcDir = L"c:\\test\\src";
CString dstDir = L"c:\\test\\dst";

CComPtr<IFileOperation> fileOp;
fileOp.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOperation);
fileOp->SetOperationFlags(FOFX_SHOWELEVATIONPROMPT);

srcDir += L"\\*";
CFileFind finder;
BOOL next = finder.FindFile(srcDir);
while (next)
{
    next = finder.FindNextFile();
    if (finder.IsDots())
        continue;

    CComPtr<IShellItem> src, dst;
    if (S_OK != SHCreateItemFromParsingName(finder.GetFilePath(), NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&src)))
        continue;

    if (S_OK != SHCreateItemFromParsingName(dstDir, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&dst)))
        continue;

    fileOp->CopyItem(src, dst, 0, NULL);
}

MessageBox(L"nothing copied so far...");
hr = fileOp->PerformOperations();
MessageBox(L"done...");
```

Comment: Did you try the FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS flag?  I re-wrote the sample using your comments.  The progress dialog does **not** appear at all.

Comment: Yes I tried the code. `SHFileOperation` works too. You are probably copying only a few files and it's set to automatically rename files, that's why nothing shows up.

Comment: I've accepted your answer after doing a little more research with the code.  The amount of files **does** impact whether the dialog will show (and, that makes logical sense).  I copied a large (gigabytes) structure and it did show consistently.  However, I did **not** need to use the FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS flag.

Comment: You are right, `FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS` is not even a valid flag, it's for `SHFileOperation` I edited the answer. You said the main problem was that some files were not being copied, maybe it has to do with another flag like `FOFX_SHOWELEVATIONPROMPT` Also I added error handling to make sure `CopyItem`'s parameters are valid.

Comment: Unrelated but important to [avoid shell extension hassles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120330-00/?p=7963), even more so if you are [using this code from a service](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150522-00/?p=45054): Make sure to additionally pass `FOFX_NO­COPY­HOOKS` to `SetOperationFlags()`.