# Invoke Windows copy from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, copy-paste

I am busy with creating a PowerShell script where a folder needs to be copied to another folder as a part of the script.
For this I would like to use the standard Windows copy interface and leverage from the prompts and selections like “There is already a file with the same name in this location.”, “Do you want to merge this folder”, “Do this for all”, etc. instead of programming this all myself.

I investigated a view directions:

- Using the [IFileOperation::CopyItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775761.aspx) method as e.g. [HowTo: Display progress dialog using IFileOperation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024157/howto-display-progress-dialog-using-ifileoperation) but I could find any hint of how to embed this in PowerShell
- Using [Verbs() Copy/Paste](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/e2617d5c-4e06-49e8-b7b8-d023b31fa750) but although the example `Invoke-FileSystemVerb -Path "C:\TestDir -Verb Cut; Invoke-FileSystemVerb -Path "\\server\share" -Verb Paste”` suggests otherwise, I can paste files that are manually copied/cut but could not copy/cut files with using the CmdLet or simply using the Verb.DoIt() method (I suspect this for a security reason).
- Simulate a drag-drop?

But could not find any working solution.
Any suggestion how to do this from PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this to extract from ZIP files which seems to come up with all the prompts and progress bar:

```
$shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
$folder = $shell.NameSpace(“$path\Folder”)
$shell.NameSpace($otherpath).CopyHere($folder)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was lonking for such a solution for hours and this seems indeed to do the trick.

Comment: Instead of the `ForEach` loop it is better to copy all items at once: `.CopyHere($zip.items())` this will also show the "_Do this for all_" for the root items.

Comment: I modified it to copy the entire folder rather than its contents, which is far neater IMO (unless you want to only copy the contents)

Comment: The `CopyHere()` hint help me a lot but I am using a little different implementation as I want to copy all the items in the $Folder and not the top folder itself: `$Shell.Namespace($LocalDestination).CopyHere($Shell.NameSpace($RemoteSource).Items())`